# .innerHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

Its so plain simple, I can not comprehend, what is the issue?
All DOMs are created before I pick them, used either a document.getElementsByClass or just the dom object created itself, not working... I wonder where did I do wrong?

```
    var wrapperDom = document.createElement('div');
    wrapperDom.className = 'sticky-state-wrapper';

    var containerDom = document.createElement('div');
    containerDom.className = 'sticky-state-container';

    var targetDom = document.createElement('div');
    targetDom.className = 'sticky-state-target';
    targetDom.style.height='50px';
        targetDom.innerHTML("My Sticky Component");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/cv3mpL4k/1/

Comment: Well, `innerHTML` is not a function... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: should be `targetDom.innerHTML = "My Sticky Component";`

Comment: try  targetDom.innerHTML="My Sticky Component";

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not a function. It's a property. Try this instead:

```
targetDom.innerHTML = "My Sticky Component";
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because, like elclanrs said, innerHTML is not a function.

Use it like this:
`targetDom.innerHTML = "My Sticky Component";`